# Get count from select

Tags: mysql

my sql code is

```
select pr.category_id FROM products p
LEFT JOIN products_category_rel pr ON p.id = pr.product_id
left JOIN products_design pd ON p.id = pd.product_id 
LEFT JOIN products_producer pp ON pp.id = p.producer_id
group by pr.category_id, p.id
```

sql return array [1436, 1436, ..., 1436, 1437,...,1437] where the value 1436 is in the array 150 times and 1437 is 100 times

I need retrun columns -> 1436 | 150 , 1437 | 100

can you help me?

Comment: I see your code, but without the data from the tables. it means nothing https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Use `COUNT(*)` and `GROUP BY pr.category_id`

Comment: https://mattmazur.com/2017/11/01/counting-in-mysql-when-joins-are-involved/

Comment: relationship table `products` -> `products_category_rel ` (n:n),
relationship table `products` -> `products_design ` 1:n.
relationship table `products` -> `products_producer` 1:1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select pr.category_id, COUNT(pr.category_id) AS category_count
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN products_category_rel pr ON p.id = pr.product_id
left JOIN products_design pd ON p.id = pd.product_id 
LEFT JOIN products_producer pp ON pp.id = p.producer_id
group by pr.category_id
order by pr.category_id;
```